# how to concat two rdd in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
rdd_1 = [(k1, (v1, v2)), (k2, (v3, v4, v5))]
rdd_2 = [(v1, (w1)), (v3, (w2, w3)), (v5, (w4))]
```

I want to get a new rdd like this `rdd = [(k1, (w1)), (k2, (w2, w3, w4))]`

How to do this in spark with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap`, `join` and `groupByKey` should do the job (used in this order).

Comment: do you mean getting [(v1, k1), (v2, k1), (v3, k2) ..] firstly, then doing `join` ? i can not figure it out, can you explain it more detail? thank you.

Comment: Sure, can you first update question with the code that is not working? I can help you finding bug in your method

Comment: I have done it successfully according to your method. thanks very much.

Comment: @祝方泽: If the answer is working pls. vote-up/ accept as owner. It would be pointer to others. Also next time pls see that the code you have tried and problems you are facing you can mention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code in Scala. This code is basically using three transformations flatMap, join and groupBy. Problem here is that the join and groupBy key has to be different. So first we use flatMap on rdd_1 to get a rdd of **(v,k)** type. Now we have rdds of type (v,k) and (v,List(w)), so we do join based on **v**. Type of our joined rdd will be **(v,(k,List(w)))**. Finally we groupBy **K** by passing a function **x => x._2._1** to the groupBy transformation. Below is the entire code:-->

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("k1", List("v1", "v2")), ("k2", List("v3", "v4", "v5"))))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("v1", List("w1")), ("v3", List("w2", "w3")), ("v5", List("w4"))))
val flattenedRdd1 = rdd1 flatMap {
  case (x, y) => {
    val lb = new ListBuffer[(String, String)]
    y.foreach { v => lb += ((v, x)) }
    lb
  }
}
val joined = flattenedRdd1 join rdd2
val result = joined.groupBy { x => x._2._1 }.map {
  case (x, itr) => {
    val lb = new ListBuffer[String]
    itr.foreach {
      case (f, s) => {
        lb.++=(s._2)
      }
    }
    (x, lb)
  }
}
result.foreach(println(_)).
```